# loop in URL, How fix this?

Tags: .htaccess, loops, url

I generated a sitemap.xml but prints url element multiple times in loop

Example

```
http://www.domain.com/en/en/en/en/en/en/legal-advice
```

How I fix this? The page is in PHP with framework Codeigniter.

Comment: Without knowing the codes & structures, how can we know ?

Comment: Please add your code and structure of your website to your question.

Comment: If I navigate in the site, I don't see the bucle. Before the page is in Wordpress and now is in CodeIgniter but the domain is the same.

Comment: @Nartronic - That doesn't help. We need to see your code. We don't need to know your setup. Just the code is fine.

Comment: was a relative URL in the message cookie...